# Copy an excel file and rename it

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy an excel file (excel 2013) of the following way:

When i open the nameofthefile, at first, a macro start automatically and work of this way:

```
1.- Explore the actual date of the computer
2.- If the actual computer date is > of the last save date of the nameofthefile then
2.1.- copy the file on the same directory
2.2.- rename the copied file to nameofthefile_dd_mm_yyyy (the actual date)
2.3.- end macro
3.- If the actual computer date is <= of the last save date of the file then do nothing an end macro.
```

any ideas?
Thanks...

Comment: We won't just code for you, please post any attempts and code that you already have!

Comment: Ideas? Yes. Fire up the macro recorder and perform the steps you want to perform. Then clean up the code and work in the conditions.

Comment: Thanks for... i'll do that... sorry for. It's my first time that i have this problem and i don't know how to handle...

Answer (score 0):

If i open one of the copied files, should it copy itself again, if it meets the requirements? Should the new date then be placed after the old or will it replace the old one?

Comment: Very clever question...
No, only the last file of the group is opened for editing... the another is a daily backup. For example... we have an original file for the start work... then the next day the original file is autobackuped whit the date before add to the name: Then the next day we open the original file, and so on...

Comment: So you always open the same file and when you open it, it should be copy-saved to the same folder with the date added to the file name?